# Modify List Paragraph style so that spacing between items is different to after

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In Word 2010, is it possible to set specific paragraph spacing between each item in a list, but then have a different value for after the list?

This must be done within the **List Paragraph** style.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

---

## Example

For example, if I were to have the following list I'd like it spaced as specified -

1. Item number 1 (4pt after)
2. Item number 2 (4pt after)
3. Item number 3 (4pt after)
4. Item number 4 (15pt after)

Rather than applying this to a single list I wish to apply it to the **List Paragraph** style, thus selecting items 1-3 to set the spacing differently from item 4 is not an option.

---

## What I've tried

1. I first modified the style as below, but as mentioned above the spacing after item number 4 is also set to 4pt, which is no good for me.
2. I created a copy of the **List Paragraph** style and set the spacing after to 15pt.  However doing this separates the last item from the list, creating a secondary list.  Do this means that, for every list, I'd have to adjust the starting at number for the last item, which would be far too time consuming.
3. I briefly experimented with line-spacing, but this is not the way forward.

[image: Paragraph settings]

Answer (score 0):

You should set "after" to 15 pts and check the box "don't add space...". You can't specify 4 pts exactly but you can get similar result with setting line spacing.

Comment: Thanks, but this is no good; line spacing is not the answer. Line spacing will adjust the spacing between each **line**, not list item, thus if a list item wraps the spacing will be off.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to apply a style to the succeeding paragraph that applies more space before. Not the desired functionality, but at least the desired outcome.